# Change height and width of ImageViews proportionally

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-autolayout

I have a View like shown in the image. Leading and trailing distance is increasing when showing view on different screens. How do I make it look good on every screen by using constraints.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "look good"?

Comment: Use horizontal `Stack View`

Comment: best way is use StackView >> distribution = fill equally

Comment: All images height and width increase or decrease equally @Agent Smith

Comment: It is recommended to add your tried code or any efforts you have made till now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UIStackView` (Horizontal) with distribution Equally , here is a run on iPhone

[image]

Also with iPad

[image]

Comment: And set the contentmode to aspect fit :)

Comment: Is it possible to adjust height of stackview correspond to width of single item in the stackView?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following constraints

1. Assign equal width from image1 to image2.
2. Assign horizontal spacing between both image.
3. Assign leading space from image1 to its superview.
4. Assign trailing space from image2 to its superview.
5. Assign top space to both the buttons.

Then do this same steps for image3 and image4